# The default number of rows for "Add more rows" at the bottom of Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

At the bottom of Google Sheet web application, 
there is an 'Add' button and '1000' is the default number of rows to be added.
Can I change this default number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there's no way to change that value, if the motivation behind your question is to reduce the number of unnecessary rows in your spreadsheet, I have a  workaround.

I wrote a Google Apps Script that:

- uses a time-based trigger set to hourly,
- loops through each individual sheet in a spreadsheet,
- identifies each sheet's last populated row,
- deletes any rows below that one.

## Script

```
// people accidentally press the button "add 1000 rows" at the bottom of the sheet. 
// Run this script every hour to clean that off the bottom of the sheet.
    function deleteBogusBottomRows(sheet) {
      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
      var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
      //Logger.log("last row with content is "+lastRow);
      if( lastRow < maxRows ) {
        // Rows start at "1" - this will delete the last rows, which have no content.
        sheet.deleteRows(lastRow + 1, maxRows - lastRow); 
      }
    }


function deleteBogusBottomRowsInAllSheets() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  for (var i=0; i < ss.getNumSheets(); i++){
    deleteBogusBottomRows(sheets[i]);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not possible, though it has been brought up on Google Forums here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/8cddwCdFn7w/SUmXk1N8YfAJ

Comment: The link no longer points to a valid post.